# Prove that an entire function with modulus bounded from below by a polynomial is a polynomial itself.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Suppose $f$ is an entire function and that $\exists k > 0, R > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(z)| > k|z|^n$ whenever $|z| > R$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

I am not sure how to go about this and I would greatly appreciate some hints.

Comment: Think of the singularity of $f(1/z)$ at 0. Use your condition to rule out an essential singularity. Then use the factorization theorem.